# Conditionally changing CSS of a div generated via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of a specific question but I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I am basically filling a div (`id = 'content'`) with names from an array and numbers from an API. This part is all fine and the div is appended with the correct content. However, I am now trying to style that content and it is proving more difficult.

What I am trying to do is to get only the numbers to change colour depending on how high they are. My thinking was to do this by generating a span tag around the numbers via jquery and then edit the css of this span after it had been generated. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working and I'm wondering if it would be better to split the function up or use a completely different approach?

Any advice would be very welcome!

The code is below:

```js
var cities = ['London', 'New York', 'Beijing', 'Shanghai', 'Tokyo', 'Rotterdam', 'Seoul', 'Paris', 'Hong Kong']

function colors(x, y) {
  if (x <= 50) {
    $('#'+ y).css({
      'color': 'lime',
    });
  } else if (x >= 51 && x <= 120) {
    $('#'+ y).css({
      'color': 'orange',
    });
  } else {
    $('#'+ y).css({
      'color': 'red',
    });
  }
}


function getAqi(z) {
 z = z.replace(/\s/g, '')
 var URL = "https://api.waqi.info/feed/location/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246"
  var URL = URL.replace("location", z)
 $.getJSON(URL, function(obj) {
    var num = obj.data.aqi;
    var numstring = num.toString();
    var span = "<span id="+z+">" + numstring + "</span>"
    colors(num, z)
    $('#content').append(z + '&nbsp;');
    $('#content').append(span + '&nbsp;' + "|" + '&nbsp;');
  });
}

var i = 0;
for (;cities[i];) {
 var city = cities[i]
  getAqi(city);
  i++
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the `span`'s before appending them to the HTML which returns null. Call the `colors` function after the append.

```js
var cities = ['London', 'New York', 'Beijing', 'Shanghai', 'Tokyo', 'Rotterdam', 'Seoul', 'Paris', 'Hong Kong']

function colors(x, y) {
  debugger;
  if (x <= 50) {
    $('#' + y).css({
      'color': 'lime',
    });
  } else if (x >= 51 && x <= 120) {
    $('#' + y).css({
      'color': 'orange',
    });
  } else {
    $('#' + y).css({
      'color': 'red',
    });
  }
}


function getAqi(z) {
  z = z.replace(/\s/g, '')
  var URL = "https://api.waqi.info/feed/location/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246"
  var URL = URL.replace("location", z)
  $.getJSON(URL, function(obj) {
    var num = obj.data.aqi;
    var numstring = num.toString();
    var span = "<span id=" + z + ">" + numstring + "</span>"
    $('#content').append(z + '&nbsp;');
    $('#content').append(span + '&nbsp;' + "|" + '&nbsp;');
    colors(num, z);
  });
}

var i = 0;
for (; cities[i];) {
  var city = cities[i]
  getAqi(city);
  i++
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `colors()` after `$('#content').append(span + '&nbsp;' + "|" + '&nbsp;')`

```js
var cities = ['London', 'New York', 'Beijing', 'Shanghai', 'Tokyo', 'Rotterdam', 'Seoul', 'Paris', 'Hong Kong']

function colors(x, y) {
  if (x <= 50) {
    $('#' + y).css({
      'color': 'lime',
    });
  } else if (x >= 51 && x <= 120) {
    $('#' + y).css({
      'color': 'orange',
    });
  } else {
    $('#' + y).css({
      'color': 'red',
    });
  }
}


function getAqi(z) {
  z = z.replace(/\s/g, '')
  var URL = "https://api.waqi.info/feed/location/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246"
  var URL = URL.replace("location", z)
  $.getJSON(URL, function(obj) {
    var num = obj.data.aqi;
    var numstring = num.toString();
    var span = "<span id=" + z + ">" + numstring + "</span>"
    $('#content').append(z + '&nbsp;');
    $('#content').append(span + '&nbsp;' + "|" + '&nbsp;');
    colors(num, z);
  });
}

var i = 0;
for (; cities[i];) {
  var city = cities[i]
  getAqi(city);
  i++
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the position to call the function colors this must be to the final in the function getAqi

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
var cities = ['London', 'New York', 'Beijing', 'Shanghai', 'Tokyo', 'Rotterdam', 'Seoul', 'Paris', 'Hong Kong']

function colors(x, y) {
  if (x <= 50) {
    $('#'+ y).css({
      'color': 'lime',
    });
  } else if (x >= 51 && x <= 120) {
    $('#'+ y).css({
      'color': 'orange',
    });
  } else {
    $('#'+ y).css({
      'color': 'red',
    });
  }
}


function getAqi(z) {
    z = z.replace(/\s/, '')
    var URL = "https://api.waqi.info/feed/location/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246"
  var URL = URL.replace("location", z)
    $.getJSON(URL, function(obj) {
    var num = obj.data.aqi;
    var numstring = num.toString();
    var span = "<span id="+z+">" + numstring + "</span>"
    $('#content').append(z + '&nbsp;');
    $('#content').append(span + '&nbsp;' + "|" + '&nbsp;');
    colors(num, z)
  });
}

var i = 0;
for (;cities[i];) {
    var city = cities[i]
  getAqi(city);
  i++
}       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```